# how to make the first value NULL or 0 (before putting values) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have a task to build a table in SQL Server, the task is to have 2 football teams match.
but before starts and ends and then putting the values of the results (HostTeam) (AwayTeam) and (WinnerTeam), they have to be 0-0 at (HostTeam)(AwayTeam) columns and NULL on the (WinnerTeam) column.

"When adding a game record, the starting score should be 0-0 and the winner team name should be empty"

Comment: Please post your create table statements.

Comment: This appears to be a homework question.

Comment: Yes, that's something I got stuck in my homework,
"When adding a game record, the starting score should be 0-0 and the winner team name should be empty"
SCORE is a column and WINNER TEAM is another column

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to to explicitly give you the answer because this seems like you're asking for the answer to a homework/quiz question. That being said, here is some help in the right direction.

You have 2 options, either write out the CREATE TABLE script yourself, or use the built in tools provided within SSMS. Either way, you will name your table, create your desired columns/fields, give those columns/fields a type, determine whether they are allowed to be empty or not (Nullable), and you can then set DEFAULT values (NULL, 0, etc.)

*If you have any code showing your current attempt, please post that and we can go from there.*

Comment: Yes, that's something I got stuck in my homework,
"When adding a game record, the starting score should be 0-0 and the winner team name should be empty"
SCORE is a column and WINNER TEAM is another column, I just need to know how set the starting values to 0 and to NULL at the begging, nothing else,can someone give me an example of how to do this thing in SQL Server?

Answer (score -1):

As you can see bellow you have some options about your default value.

- AUTO_INCREMENT means x++
- DEFAULT NULL means The default value of this    column is null
- NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' means The deafault Value is NOT    NULL but 0 (you
  can define it yourself)

  > CREATE TABLE `test_user` (
  >       `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Id Auto_Increment Default Null',
  >       `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No_name' COMMENT 'Varchar Name
  >   Default Value No_Name',
  >       `surname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Varchar Name Default NULL',
  >       `num` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Default integer value 0',
  >                PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  >               ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: I gave you an example since you don provide code. Your relation table should have the same definitions which means that you should provide the Default value in order to specify which would be the default situation . In your situation I guess the Home Team And Away team are instances in the same table team so the current_score column must be set to DEFAULT '0' etc.

Comment: that was not me, thanks a lot, you have helped me.
So now at your example, when I will Execute the create table I can see 0 in the num column?

Comment: You will see 0 in the column or Null etc , when you insert a record . That's ofc if you don't send send data for the specific column.

For instance when you create the Home_Team record you will not insert the score , it will take automatic the value 0. Then you can update that value.